# filling static title list and dynamic value lists at the same place in code and most efficiently

Tags: c++, performance, templates

i have some code that recursively extracts values from hierarchical data structures like:

```
struct A{
  int i;
  int t;
};


struct B{
  float64 fl;
  A       a;
  QString str;
};


struct C{
  bool cb;
  A a;
  B b;
};
```

At the moment the structures itself implement a fillData-function that fills some key-value map with there data and sub data.
for example:

```
void C::fillData(DataMap* io_map){
  (*io_map)["cb"] = cb;
  DataMap* am = new DataMap();
  DataMap* am = new DataMap();
  a.fillData(am); 
  b.fillData(bm); 
  (*io_map)["a"] = am;
  (*io_map)["b"] = bm;
}
```

The data structure are much more complexer and not all values will be output.
The further steps are writing the extracted data to some csv via some generic datamap2csv component.

The thing is this lately became some bottleneck, so i want to change the way the data extraction works without losing much flexibility.

Since the data at the end have to be transfomed into strings in either case i first will drop the multi data type container and do the conversion at the start. I also want to reduce the overhead of the data description tags (the former map keys) since the data for one suboject is always in the same oder.

My final outcome should be some mechanism that allows to fill some structure that contains the pointer/reference to a static QStringList with the column headers and anoter QStringlist with the stringyfied values.

but i want not to lose the possibility to do both definition on the same place (i do not want to create a header-list on one place and the data

So the final code should look similar to this:

```
struct FeatureData{
  const QStringList* header;
  QStringList        data;
}


template <>
FeatureDataFill<A>(const A* o, FeatureData* io_fd){
  io_fd->add("integral", o->i);
  io_fd->add("time", o->t);
}

template <>
FeatureDataFill<B>(const B* o, FeatureData* io_fd){
  io_fd->add("fl", o->fl);
  io_fd->add("a",  &o->a);
  io_fd->add("text", o->str);
}

template <>
FeatureDataFill<C>(const C* o, FeatureData* io_fd){
  io_fd->add("cb", o->cb);
  io_fd->add("a", &o->a);
  io_fd->add("b", &o->b);
}
```

the following codes should produce the following outputs:

```
A a = {2 ,3};
B b = {1.0, {4,5}, "hallo"};
C c = {true, {6,7}, {2.0, {8,9}, "bye"}};
FeatureData dataA;
FeatureDataFill(&a, &dataA);
// dataA.header ->  "integral", "time"
// dataA.data   ->  "2", "3"
FeatureData dataB;
FeatureDataFill(&b, &dataB);
// dataA.header ->  "fl", "a/integral", "a/time", "str"
// dataA.data   ->  "1.0", "4", "5", "hallo"

FeatureData dataC;
FeatureDataFill(&c, &dataC);
// dataA.header ->  cb "a/integral", "a/time", "b/fl", "b/a/integral", "b/a/time", "b/str"
// dataA.data   ->  "true", "6", "7", "2.0", "8", "9", "bye"
```

I am not sure how to build up the template architecture to achieve this.
I tried a bit but i have not come up with particularly ideas.
One of the one i had was to utilize some template class that provides a static `fillData(T* data)` method and some `insertValue(const char* key, QString value)` method -pointer. 
after the first use of the `fillData` method the `insertValue` pointer should be redirected to some other method that just ignores the key since the header list is built up after the first run and can be reused every time. To save further efford of construction/destruction this method should only get a const char pointer instead of a `QString` object..

But i haven't got the whole picture now. Some parts of the puzzle always do not want to match.

Does anybody has additional hints or better suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

One thing that is probably a performance killer is the dynamic allocation,  the other operations performed there are relatively harmless. Involved in dynamic allocations are QStringList and QString (and DataMap in the first version of the code). I wonder if the use of `new` in the first version is justified and also what wonders DataMap is working behind the scenes. This may not be easy to change though.

Then, you already mentioned that you don't want to extract the header data more than once, because it is always the same. Also, there is another thing that will always be the same, and that is the numeric index of a particular field! In other words, you don't need a map for the values, but just an indexed list (I'm not sure which of these QStringList is)! With that in mind, the code should look like this:

```
template<typename T>
void extract_header(StringList& l, T const& t, String prefix);
template<>
void extract_header<A>(StringList& l, A const& a, String prefix)
{
    l.add(prefix + "integral");
    l.add(prefix + "time");
}
template<>
void extract_header<B>(StringList& l, B const& b, String prefix)
{
    l.add(prefix + "fl");
    extract_header(l, b.a, prefix + "a/");
    l.add(prefix + "text");
}
```

Similarly the functions to extract the actual values:

```
template<typename T>
void extract_value(StringList& l, T const& t);
template<>
void extract_value<A>(StringList& l, A const& a)
{
    l.add(a.integral);
    l.add(a.time);
}
template<>
void extract_value<B>(StringList& l, B const& b)
{
    l.add(b.fl);
    extract_value(l, b.a);
    l.add(b.text);
}
```

If you write an array of these structures, you then simply invoke `extract_header()` once and `extract_value()` for each element of the array.

Notes:

- I didn't retain your style of passing pointers. Your use of pointers is actually non-idiomatic C++. When you pass an object that can not be null, use a reference instead.
- `l.add()` is supposed to format the value as string and add it to the list. I guess there is some conversion code missing, but I hope you get the point.
- Since the number of elements is fixed, you could exploit this, too. Just write a similar function returning the size for the according objects. You use that to preallocate memory for the string lists.
- If you add specializations for basic types like int and float, you might be able to rewrite the specializations of the extract functions to only recursively call these. You would then have to adjust the prefix handling a bit.
- You might even be able to write template code that just visits the elements of your data and separate code that then handles it, similar to the visitor pattern. You could then reuse that to implement the various extract functions. The advantage is that you only define the structure of the data once, so you couldn't have an `extract_header<B>` that provides four fields and an `extract_value<B>` that only writes three values.
- If you have a large array of these structures that you want to write to disk, don't first convert them to string lists before writing them. The reason is that this will require all the memory to hold the actual data as strings. Instead, convert and write them one-by-one, which keeps memory requirements low and also makes it more likely that memory is still in cache.